# Rails: Form Submit Perform Two Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm creating a reminders app using Rails. I have created a `notify` action that sends a MMS message. I would now like to setup the app so when a user creates a new reminder, it also performs the `notify` action. However, I'm new to Rails and not quite sure where to begin.

It it possible to perform the notify action when a new reminder is created?

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def notify
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new 'account_sid', 'auth_token'
    message = client.messages.create from: '+18588779747', to: current_user.phone_number, body: 'First ever MyMedy notifcation test.'
    render plain: message.status
  end
end
```

**reminders_controller.rb**

```
class RemindersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reminder, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ....

  # GET /reminders/new
  def new
    @reminder = Reminder.new
  end

  def create
    @reminder = current_user.reminders.new(reminder_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reminder.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reminder, notice: 'Reminder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @reminder }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @reminder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Medy::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :reminders
  root 'reminders#index'
  post 'notifications/notify' => 'notifications#notify'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails controller actions are coupled to routes by design: they're entry points into your app that are triggered by hitting certain URLs with certain HTTP methods. In your case, you don't really want the two actions to be the same (since one of them needs to create a reminder and the other doesn't). What you really want is another object that handles the sending of MMS messages, and that's invoked from both controllers:

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
def notify
  message = MyNotifier.notify(current_user, "My message")
  render plain: message.status
end
```

**reminders_controller.rb**

```
...
if @reminder.save
  MyNotifier.notify(current_user, "My message")
...
```

Or something like that, and then have your class:

**my_notifier.rb**

```
class MyNotifier
  def self.notify(user, message)
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new YOUR_CLIENT_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
    client.messages.create from: '+18588779747', to: user.phone_number, body: message
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the edits! I'll update my credentials. I forgot I hardcoded the ENV variables for development.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. As a general rule, don't let yourself be constrained by the basic types that Rails gives you out of the box: not everything in your app is going to be a model or a controller. The more you extract functionality like this into small single-purpose objects, the easier of a time you'll have re-using them in different places, and the easier it will be to maintain your app over time. The last thing you want is to keep adding bits to your actions every time you want a new feature, until you wind up with a 1000-line controller.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, should I move my_notifier.rb into a "classes" directory? Currently, I have it inside the controllers directory.

Comment: There are many different schools of thought on that topic. Lots of people put "utility" classes like this in `lib`, while others make other subdirectories under `app` for specific types of objects (e.g. `services`, `queries`, `presenters`, etc.) Some people like having domain objects in `models` even though they're not ActiveRecord::Base subclasses. This blog post has some nice ideas: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/